# How to use secrets as interpolation variables in Docker-Compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, string-interpolation, docker-secrets

This is part of my `docker-compose.yaml`:

```
  gql:
    build: 
      context: ./graphql
    container_name: cyp-gql
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: 
      - ./.env
    depends_on: 
      - db
    ports: 
      - 5000:5000
    command: [
      "--owner-connection", "postgres://${NAME_ADMIN}:${PWD_ADMIN}@172.27.0.2:5432/${DB_NAME}", 
      .....
```

`.env` file contains all variables and this service is running OK.

I wanna use `secrets` for this service as interpolation variables, like this:

```
  gql:
    build: 
      context: ./graphql
    container_name: cyp-gql
    restart: unless-stopped
    secrets:
      - db_pwd
      - db_dbname
    env_file: 
      - ./.env
    environment:
      - DB_NAME=/run/secrets/db_dbname
      - PWD_ADMIN=/run/secrets/db_pwd
    depends_on: 
      - db
    ports: 
      - 5000:5000
    command: [
      "--owner-connection", "postgres://${NAME_ADMIN}:${PWD_ADMIN}@172.27.0.2:5432/${DB_NAME}", 
      .....
```

Where `.env` file contains NAME_ADMIN variable only.

But I'm getting these warning messages:

```
WARN[0000] The "DB_NAME" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string. 
WARN[0000] The "PWD_ADMIN" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
```

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: try env('DB_NAME') instead of DB_NAME

Comment: Not sure this is the crux of the issue, but please avoid naming your `env_file` as `".env"`, as this is a special filename… see e.g. https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env-file

Comment: @Pradeep I've tried with `${env(DB_NAME)}` and `env(DB_NAME)` but not working.